# Astropy time: is it possible to use negative dates?

Tags: astropy, precession

The goal is to find precessed coordinates for BCE dates.

```
from astropy.time import Time
equinox = Time('-0500-01-01')
```

is just not working, though '0500-01-01' works just fine.  Is there a time format that allows BCE dates or years before present or anything like that?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: The documenation https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/time/index.html  It says "iso 8601 compliant date" but iso just says implementations may use an expanded date format, by prior agreement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Use the `format='fits'` to the time function.

> FITS format: “[±Y]YYYY-MM-DD[THH:MM:SS[.sss]]”.
>
> ISOT but can give signed five-digit year (mostly for negative years);

([documentation](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/time/index.html#:%7E:text=2000.45-,fits,%E2%80%982000%2D01%2D01T00%3A00%3A00.000%E2%80%99,-gps))